# What is the meaning of Vce in DC current gain?

Tags: bjt, gain

In the datasheet of the 2N2222 there are several DC current gain (h<sub>FE</sub>) values.

Assume that the load in my circuit is 20 mA. What h<sub>FE</sub> value should I choose?

And what is the meaning of V<sub>CE</sub> for the h<sub>FE</sub> value; what does it tell?

[image: datasheet]

Comment: Vce should be the voltage applied across collector and emitter.

Answer (score 2):

The simplifies model of a transistor is that you can multiply Ib by hFE to get Ice. But if you look at the datasheet you'll find graphs with curves that show, that hFE is not constant.

hFE depends on the Voltage across Collector-Emitter (Vce) and the current trough the Base (Ib). That's why any number for hFE is only true for a certain combination (or small region of combinations) of Vce and Ib.

So the hFE number is only a rough guide to compare different transistors but nothing you'll be able to engineer your device around.

As to what transistor to select: load current is by far not enough information to give you any advice there. In what mode (swittcing / saturation or linear) are you working? What Voltage? What does your circuit look like? What speed do you need? How are you driving the transistor?